# How to sort checkboxes by class, value, and checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, checkbox

I have a div, `#subfilterNamesContainer`, that contains a list of checkboxes. I am trying to write a function that will sort the checkboxes in to 3 sections.

- Checkboxes with `class="default"` should be at the top ordered by value, regardless if it's checked or not.
- Then I need to list the checkboxes that are NOT `class="default"` that are checked, ordered by value.
- Finally I need to show all the NOT `class="default"` that are unchecked and again ordered by value.

It would be ideal to have a horizontal rule between these three sections as well.

How can I do this task? The goal is to show the user default checkboxes at the top, followed by the non-default checkboxes that are checked, followed by the non-default, unchecked ones. This doesn't need to be responsive to the users checking, only when this new function (let's called it `sortGiveNamesFilter`) is called.

```
<div id="subfilterNamesContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" value="X"> X <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="A"> A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="A B" class="default"> A B <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="A A" class="default"> A A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="F"> F <br> <--THiS ONE WILL BE CHECKED
    <input type="checkbox" value="E"> E <br> <--THiS ONE WILL BE CHECKED
</div>
```

Final result when my new function is called should be:

```
<div id="subfilterNamesContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" value="A A" class="default"> A A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="A B" class="default"> A B <br>
    <hr>
    <input type="checkbox" value="E"> E <br> <--THiS ONE WILL BE CHECKED
    <input type="checkbox" value="F"> F <br> <--THiS ONE WILL BE CHECKED
    <hr>
    <input type="checkbox" value="A"> A <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="X"> X <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is for helping you debug code that you have written to solve your issue. It is not a code writing service. Please edit your question to include any JS code you have attempted to write yourself to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not even sure where to begin on this or how to handle this type of situation. I'm not aware of any jQuery functions I can call that will pull out my items to sort by class then value.

Comment: To do the actual sorting of the elements you can use the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you would need to amend your HTML slightly so that when the checkboxes are re-arranged the text node next to them is moved as well. To do this, you can surround both nodes with a `label` element, like this:

```
<div id="subfilterNamesContainer">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="X"> X
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="A"> A
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="A A" class="default"> A A
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="A B" class="default"> A B
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="F" checked="true"> F
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="E" checked="true"> E
    </label>
</div>
```

To achieve the sorting of the `label` elements can use the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method, providing your own function which defines the sorting logic to place the `.default` checkboxes first, then those which are checked, and then not checked, with each sub section ordered by the `value` of the checkbox. Once the sorting is complete you can search for the last `.default` and `:checked` elements and add an `hr` after them. Something like this:

```
function sortGiveNamesFilter() {
    $('#subfilterNamesContainer label').sort(function(a, b) {
        var $a = $(a).find(':checkbox'),
            $b = $(b).find(':checkbox');

        if ($a.hasClass('default') && !$b.hasClass('default'))
            return -1;
        else if (!$a.hasClass('default') && $b.hasClass('default'))
            return 1;

        if ($a.is(':checked') && !$b.is(':checked'))
            return -1;
        else if (!$a.is(':checked') && $b.is(':checked'))
            return 1;

        if ($a.val() < $b.val())
            return -1;
        else if ($a.val() > $b.val())
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }).appendTo('#subfilterNamesContainer');

    $('#subfilterNamesContainer .default:last, #subfilterNamesContainer :checked:last').closest('label').after('<hr />');
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tf0qyy55/)

Note that the JS code can be made shorter with the use of ternary expressions, I just kept it verbose to make it obvious how it was working.

Comment: Oh wow, this is so helpful.  Thank you!  Now, I really understand what's it's doing.  Looking at online examples wasn't helping much, but this is brilliant.